# Unable to display last check in comment in page layout

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, version-comments

I have one page layout in which I have placed some fields of content type as label mode, which display the respective value of field while the page is in edit mode.

I want to display the last check in comments in the page, for programmatically getting the comments there is one property `SPFileVersion.CheckInComment`. But I want to display it in the Page Layout.

I have placed following mark up in Page Layout to get the comments but is not working.

```
<tr>
    <th><label id="lblCheckinComment">Comment: </label></th>
    <td><SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="_CheckinComment" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:FieldValue></td>
</tr>
```

How can I get comments?

Comment: In client browser I can see the value in the field `_CheckinComment` in FieldValueAsText, but in the same field value is not displayed in `FieldValueAsHtml`

Answer (score 0):

Searched over google for hours but not helped. So finally, I went through JavaScript and REST query. So finally, to get the Last Check In comment I needed to modify my code of Page Layout.

The page layout contains below markup:

```
<tr>
    <th><label id="lblComment">Comment: &nbsp;</label>  </th>
    <td id="tdCheckInComment"></td>
</tr>
```

Create one JavaScript file and give the name whatever you want. In my case, I created `GetLastCheckInComment.js`.

The JavaScript file contains below code:

```
window.onload= function(){
    // getting the GUID of list.
    var listGUID = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
    // getting the item id
    var itemId = _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId;

    // clearing the value inside the tdCheckInComment
    $("#tdCheckInComment").html('');
    // checking if list guid found or not.
    if(listGUID)
    {
        //removing {} from the variable.
        listGUID = listGUID.replace(/[{}]/g, "");
        // checkin if item id is found or not.
        if(itemId)
        {
            var comment = GetLastCheckInComment(listGUID,itemId);
            if(comment)
            {
                $("#tdCheckInComment").html(comment);
            }
        }
    }
}
function GetLastCheckInComment(listGUID,itemId) {
    var returnValue;
    try {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listGUID+ "')/items("+itemId+")/File/CheckInComment",
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                returnValue =data.d.CheckInComment;

            },
            error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.error('Error while getting the last check in comment.');
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Load JavaScript file in the Page Layout. You can give reference of it in `<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">`.

And finally I was able to see the last check in comment after the page is loaded.

Hope this helps others too...!!!
Thanks.